# Questions that provide speculative answers

Tags: discussion, questions

Related to the question [Could there be a sequel to Freedom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/292/could-there-be-a-sequel-to-freedom)

I really think it is very interesting to know if there will be a sequel, but I think questions like that one only result in vague/speculative answers.

So what do you think? Should those questions be allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are forum-style speculation questions, and should be closed.

Comment: I agree. Even on a forum, they wouldn't have an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Some of these questions have definite answers. If you ask "Could there be a sequel to *A Fire Upon the Deep* by Vernor Vinge?", then the answer is, "It's called *The Children of the Sky*, and it's scheduled for publication later this year", which seems like a pretty useful and non-speculative answer.

So I don't think we can ban questions with speculative answers, since the person asking the question is likely to have no way to know whether or not it's speculative.

Comment: That's not *could*, that's *will*. In other words, the solution, in my mind is that we need to crack down on speculative *answers* more than we do speculative *questions*.

Answer (score 3):

They are clearly not answerable. They can't even make it into a wiki like: *What are some good stories about X or written by Y?*

Answer (score 0):

If the question has an answer, such as "Yes ... there will be a sequel and it will be on such and such date," then it's all good. Mere speculation is not and I think the problem, as has been noted, is more with the answer than the question.