# This question about movie–only Treebeard quote seems to have too many speculative answers

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

[Treebeard: "I always like going South, somehow it feels like going downhill." - Is it really?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184235/)

The question is not asking for speculation — as would obviously not be accepted by most here.[1](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/68218)

I really think most of the answers are subpar.  I'm opening this topic here to discuss whether my assessment is correct and to hopefully get some attention to, if necessary, improving the answers.

At time of writing this, there are 5 answers.
The [accepted one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184242/68218) has many reviewers and downvotes that seem to agree with my assessment:  pure fanon, methinks.
[Another](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184243/68218) offers probable and believable suppositions for why the line was included in the movie — but seems rather simplistic for me:  as if it didn't even take the line at face value but really misinterpreted it.
Another [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184279/68218) is obviously unsubstantiated, but upvotes tell me that many drive–by voters agree.  If its purported quote actually exists, then I think it would be the best answer and I'd upvote it.
[One answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184241/68218) seems plausible, but it in no way makes an effort to support its claim.  Fanon, but better than the accepted one.
Of course, there is also [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184339/68218), but if I had problems with it then I'd either edit, delete, or ask them in a different question.

So, prior to me flagging the answers for review, is there anything else that can be done?
Maybe I am making too big a fuss out of these answers …

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can see, all the current answers attempt to answer the question. Some are better than others, and that is what up and down votes are supposed to distinguish.

I'm afraid that the fact that you don't think some of the highly up-voted answers are good (I agree with you in one case) doesn't mean that they should be flagged. You can, as you have done, post on Meta and hope that the Meta Effect will draw additional down-votes, but I don't think that is what Meta was created for.

Comment: Although it should be noted that all users are able to edit there posts if someone has criticisms, and rather than slander posts on meta one should suggest improvements, inquire opinions or even give constructive criticism in comments.

Comment: @Edlothiad I did make comments as to your answer, but you've ignored them:  your answer misses the mark by a mile even if your suggested explanation is worth considering.  My answer attempts to explain the reason why the comment was included in the movie, whereas yours simply lays out superficial similarities.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I left comments there — either I was in error or those were deleted.  Anyway:  Why would you think that what I did was “slander”?  I was offering my opinion as to the quality of something — and I thought that I did so in an honest and impersonal manner.  I genuinely think that the answer is inadequate — of course, there's nothing I can do to get my point across if you ignore it or don't think it is worth rebuttal.  I have better things to do, but I wouldn't pursue this matter on meta if I didn't care.

Comment: @Edlothiad If I was being personal about it, I would've said things like how the answer disappoints my expectations for an answer from you.  So far as I can remember, there was only one regarding Galadriel with which I strongly disagreed or did not respect the scholarship.  Thanks for the downvotes.  Et c.